# StructScan unknown struct slice [GO]

Tags: function, struct, go

So I would like to fill any struct via the `StructScan` method and so read any data I get from the db into the regarding struct I feed the test function.

This script doesn't give any compile error (if you implement the other stuff like a db connection and so on) but still the `StructScan` method returns an error and tells me that it expects a slice of structs.

How do I create a slice of structs that I don't know the type of?

Thanks for any advice.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

var db *sql.DB

type A struct {
    Name string `db:"name"`
}
type B struct {
    Name string `db:"name"`
}

func main() {

    testA := []A{}
    testB := []B{}

    test(testA, "StructA")
    test(testB, "StructB")
}

func test(dataStruct interface{}, name string) {

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name =", name)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err := sqlx.StructScan(rows, &dataStruct)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Super late to the party, but ran into this question while researching another issue.  For others that stumble upon it, the problem is that you're passing a pointer to `dataStruct` into `StructScan()`.  `dataStruct` is an interface, and pointers to interfaces are almost always an error in Go (in fact, they removed the automatic dereferencing of interface pointers a few versions back).  You're also passing in your destination by value.

So, you are passing a pointer to an interface that holds a copy of your destination slice, when what you want instead is to pass the interface directly, and that interface to hold a pointer to your destination slice.

Instead of:

```
test(testA, "StructA")
test(testB, "StructB")
// ...
err := sqlx.StructScan(rows, &dataStruct)
```

Use:

```
test(&testA, "StructA")
test(&testB, "StructB")
// ...
err := sqlx.StructScan(rows, dataStruct)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea what the destination struct type is, use `sqlx.MapScan` or `sqlx.SliceScan`. They don't map to a struct, but both return all the columns from the query result.

See http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#altScanning

Comment: I would like to fit the data directly from the db into the regarding struct. Thats where Structscan is for right? So, you say its not possible to fill a unknown struct?

Comment: @RoyvanZanten How can sqlx figure what struct the query results match? A row from the query result looks like `name=bla` whether you inserted `A{Name: "bla"}` or `B{Name: "bla"}`

Comment: No sqlx cant figure it out, but i can give the right struct to the test function.